flutter_local_notifications: Schedule a Recurring Notification at a certain date
I'm trying to trigger a recurring/repeating notification starting at a specific date.
For example: Run a notification every 2 hours starting from August 28th 2024 at 2 PM
According to the method:


/// For example, specifying a 5 minutes repeat duration interval means
  /// the first time the notification will be an 5 minutes after the method
  /// has been called and then every 5 minutes after that.



The first notification is automatically set to the time it's called + the interval - Meaning there's no way to trigger it at a certain date.
Is there a workaround that'd allow me to set a starting date?


notificationsPlugin.periodicallyShowWithDuration(
          id,
          title,
          body,
          interval,
          await _notificationDetails(),
          androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.alarmClock,
          payload: notificationData.payload,
        );



